# What file do I import into Android Studio so that I can look at the code?

Tags: android-studio

I got an app created and the developer gave me the zip and apk files. I want to look at the code so I downloaded Android Studio but I don't know how to get the code to import so I can read the code. I have the zip files and apk file to the app but I have no idea what file I am supposed to import into Andriod Studio so I can look at the app's code.

I have read Android Developer's blog and searched on Youtube How to import existing projects into Android Studio but all the videos I have viewed are only showing out to update the girdle and not how to open the file to see the code.

Answer (score 0):

`APK` is the built, packaged, usually obfuscated and digitally signed distribution of your app, so it is for your clients and not quite an easy task to consume from a source point of view.

So assuming that the app's source is in the ZIP file, if you extract it to folder your should be able to open that folder with Android Studio IDE. On the start screen you can choose `Open an existing Android Studio package` and once it is open you can navigate the source in the Project pane.

This article describes what files are expected in a typical Android Studio project: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/#ProjectFiles - in a nutshell:

`java` folder - Contains the Java/Kotlin source code files (with `.java` or `.kt` extensions), separated by package names - usually in subdirectories - , including JUnit test code.

`res` folder Contains all non-code resources, such as XML layouts, UI strings, and bitmap images, divided into corresponding sub-directories. For more information about all possible resource types, see Providing Resources under the documentation above.

Comment: Thank you for your response muratiakos. I have been able to successfully unzip and open the folder in Android Studio but how do I know which file is the source file?

Comment: I extended now my previous answer, but since the source is made up from multiple files and usually placed in individual folders, essentially look for all the `*.java` or `*.kt` files depending if your code was written in Java or Kotlin language.

Comment: Okay thanks, Muratiakos I appreciate you taking the time to expound on the previous comment and direct me on which files to focus on.